# I have a problem with Home Page title

Tags: title, plugin-all-in-one-seo

I am using WordPress and "All in one SEO pack" plugin.

I set up the title, descriptions, and keywords, and everything is working nice on site. Then I accidentally looked for my site on Google. I enter my domain in search and when I found my site, I was surprised that my title is not the same as on my site. It's a totally different title, but the description is good. I try some changes but it's not showing in that moment when I change. I don't know what the problem can be.

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an SEO question than a WordPress one...

Changes won't happen until after Google re-crawls your site - that is, the next time a googlebot visits your site and updates their information about your site.

Wait for the next time they do. The rate/timing for the next googlebot crawl varies by site

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I was suspected that Google didn't not updated yet, but i really need it to be sure and its much better when i heard from someone that actually is good with this :D

Thanks again!